# Online streaming and on air/broadcast function for a Drupal website

Tags: media

I'm trying to figure out how to build a website for a tv using Drupal.

Going around the web I found different modules and [Videola](http://videola.tv/) distribution.

About the Videola distribution, I have not find any tutorial or something close to it.

I've found [Kaltura](http://drupal.org/project/kaltura/) , [Live Streaming](http://drupal.org/project/vls) and [VideoWhisper](http://drupal.org/project/videowhisper)

has anyone here got experience with these modules?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Octopusvideo](http://octopusvideo.org/) might suite for your requirement, this is in D7 and have lot of functionality.